# user998692 is a vote monster! Is this a bad thing?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, users

Flicking through the Voters tab under the Users page on StackOverflow, I've noticed one guy who appears to be everywhere: [user998692](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998692/user998692). user998692 is a vote monster!

**Today:** Vote Monster has earned 0 reputation and has cast 39 votes (In 4 hours of activity).
**This week:** Vote Monster has earned 0 reputation and has cast 116 votes.
**This month:** VM has earned 10 reputation and has cast 820 votes.
**This quarter:** VM has earned 136 reputation and has cast 2,000 votes.
**This year:** VM has earned 272 reputation and has cast 5,506 votes.
**Since November 2011:** VM has earned 836 reputation and has cast 15,130 votes.

Since Novermber 2011, Vote Monster has made a total of [293 actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998692/user998692?tab=activity&sort=all). This statistically means that for every action made, 51.6 votes are cast.

**All** of VM's votes are upvotes.

Is this a bad thing for SO?

Comment: No wonder he was awarded [Fanatic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/998692/user998692?tab=badges)

Comment: I wish the monster would down vote some, too; but this is nice :)

Comment: His actions amount to a total rep of 126,185. This is a rep charity.

Comment: Could become interesting when his account gets deleted some day.

Comment: Found via query: [Users who vote the most often](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/13069/users-who-vote-the-most-often-me). Other users in the top100 with 100 % upvotes are sharptooth and Tiny, but way farther.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this a bad thing for SO?

No, as long as all votes are legitimate and done after some thought it's only useful and kudos to that guy.

He probably love to just browse questions and upvote what he deems right.

Really nothing to worry about.

Comment: Honest voting is wholeheartedly approved of, in any quantity!

Comment: I find it hard to believe they haven't honestly seen a single bad post to downvote.

Comment: @Wooble Some people simply don't "believe in" down voting. They just think it's too harsh.

Comment: On some level, if they upvote enough, not upvoting something is analogous to a down vote.